# Do loop not working, request your solutions

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran95

I think it is silly to ask, but, my do loop isn't working it seems. Can someone take the time to re-check my code ?

Here's the code:

```
program hexagonal
implicit none


 integer::i,j,info
 integer::N1,N2
 real::a,E0,ts,tsp,Es,Ep
 real, parameter :: Pi = 3.1415927
 real, allocatable :: kx(:,:)
 real, allocatable ::ky(:,:)
 real, allocatable :: Epos(:,:)
 real, allocatable :: Eneg(:,:)

 namelist /model_parameters/ a,E0,ts,tsp
 namelist /lattice_size/ N1,N2
 open(unit=10, file='hexinput.txt',action="read", iostat=i)
 read(unit=10,nml=lattice_size,iostat=info)
 read(unit=10,nml=model_parameters,iostat=info)
 close(10)

  write(*,*) "N1=", N1, "N2=", N2, a, E0, ts, tsp
```

! allocate the arrays

```
  if (allocated(kx)) deallocate(kx)
   allocate(kx(N1,N2))


  if (allocated(ky)) deallocate(ky)
   allocate(ky(N1,N2))

  if (allocated(Epos)) deallocate(Epos)
   allocate(Epos(N1,N2))

  if (allocated(Eneg)) deallocate(Eneg)
   allocate(Eneg(N1,N2))

        !'Es' and 'Ep' are the orbital energies. Which can be written in the below form using 'E0' and 'ts'. 


 Es=-(E0-4.0*ts)
 Ep=(E0-4.0*ts)
```

! This is the loop that doesn't work !

```
 do i=1,N1
 do j=1,N2

 kx(i,j)=((i-1)/N1)*(2*Pi/a)+((j-1)/N2)*(2*Pi/a)

 end do
 end do


 do i=1,N1
 do j=1,N2

 ky(i,j)=((i-1)/N1)*(-2*Pi/(sqrt(3.0)*a))+((j-1)/N2)*(2*Pi/(sqrt(3.0)*a))

 end do
 end do


 do j=1,N2
 do i=1,N1
 Epos(i,j)=sqrt(-Es*(Ep+2*ts*(cos(kx(i,j))+cos(ky(i,j)))) &
            -(2*ts*(cos(kx(i,j))+cos(ky(i,j)))*(Ep-2*ts*(cos(kx(i,j))+cos(ky(i,j))))) &
            +(4*tsp**2)*((sin(kx(i,j)))**2 +(sin(ky(i,j)))**2))
  end do
  end do



  do j=1,N2
  do i=1,N1
 Eneg(i,j)=-sqrt(-Es*(Ep+2*ts*(cos(kx(i,j))+cos(ky(i,j)))) &
            -(2*ts*(cos(kx(i,j))+cos(ky(i,j)))*(Ep-2*ts*(cos(kx(i,j))+cos(ky(i,j))))) &
            +(4*tsp**2)*((sin(kx(i,j)))**2 +(sin(ky(i,j)))**2))
   end do
   end do





   !Creating the data file named "data.dat" with three columns containing 'Kx', 'Epos' and 'Eneg' values..

   open(unit=1, file='hex.dat')
    do i=1,N1
    do j=1,N2

   write(1,'(3f12.6)') kx(i,j),Epos(i,j),Eneg(i,j)

     end do 
    end do
   close(unit=1)


        !Now run the file in GNU plot.

   end program hexagonal
```

I am not able to generate the 'hex.dat' file mentioned! Also, I am pretty sure that all the other files I mentioned in the code are called perfectly.

Comment: I think the problem is on your "write" line. The values you want to write are not enclosed in the parens.

Comment: But, is parenthesis really needed for write ?

Comment: actually I guess not. What is the output?

Comment: but 1 is a reserved unit. Use 11 instead.

Comment: aren't i, j, N1 and N2 all integers? I think you will always get 0 because the way integer division works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for the answer, use REAL numbers to get a REAL result:

```
real::rN1,rN2

rN1 = REAL(N1)
rN2 = REAL(N2)

do i=1,N1
do j=1,N2

 kx(i,j)=((i-1)/rN1)*(2*Pi/a)+((j-1)/rN2)*(2*Pi/a)

end do
end do


do i=1,N1
do j=1,N2

ky(i,j)=((i-1)/rN1)*(-2*Pi/(sqrt(3.0)*a))+((j-1)/rN2)*(2*Pi/(sqrt(3.0)*a))

end do
end do
```

And, as for writing to hex.dat, 1 is a reserved UNIT for standard output. Use 11 instead:

```
open(unit=11, file='hex.dat')
do i=1,N1
do j=1,N2

 write(11,'(3f12.6)') kx(i,j),Epos(i,j),Eneg(i,j)

 end do 
end do
close(unit=11)
```

Comment: `1` isn't a reserved unit, Fortran doesn't reserve unit numbers.  On many Fortran platforms `0`,`5`, and `6` are *pre-connected* which means that the program doesn't need to `open` them.  But a program can open any of those unit numbers on another file.  Most platforms pre-connect `6` to standard output.